# Hiding Carto Sql Api Key?

Tags: javascript, php, cartodb

Currently i am loading a carto Table containing polyogns to my map on a php file using catro.js and the key is visible in javascript. Example given below is to call the sql api.

```
var layerStyle = $('#landuse-style').text();
cartodb.createLayer(CartoDbLib.map, {
  user_name: 'sandyjones',
  type: 'cartodb',
  sublayers: [{
    sql: "SELECT * FROM master " + query,
    cartocss: layerStyle,
  }],
  extra_params: {
      map_key: "myAPiKey"
  }
}
```

how to hide this api key on my server using proxy php file or a backend php file if you can suggest a code example that i can use.

sometime back i tried but i was stuck with a problem that in the url of images from carto server will contain the map key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you would need to create your own proxy. Here is a node.js-based proxy as sample: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb-api-proxy , but this is not supported code and probably it is even outdated.

If your table data is anyway public (and it will be public - via proxy also), then I'd define the table as "Public" in Carto web, then your app does not need to put API key to the request at all.